# Creating a dictionary in a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list with repeated values and I want to count them using a dictionary comprehension

Here is my initial attempt

```
number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
number_count_dict = {i:1 for i in number_list}
{k: (number_count_dict[k]+1 if k in number_count_dict() else 1) for k in number_list}
```

Is there a way of achieving this without initialising the dictionary?

Comment: Can't you use `collections.Counter`, or `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: `{k:number_list.count(k) for k in number_list}` will give desired output but it's
 inefficient. And what's up with using `collections.Counter`?

Comment: You can use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) when incrementing values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this example for your question:

```
 numbers = [5,3,3,4,2]
```

and let us say if you would like to turn it into a dictionary where the key is the index and value is the element in the list. Then you could trt something like this:

```
{index:numbers[index] for index in range(0,len(numbers))}
```

Here's the result:

```
{0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count repetitions only (>1)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
>>> {i:j for i,j in Counter(x).items() if i>1}
{2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves out a couple of important points. What is the minimum and maximum numbers you want in the dictionary? Do you want numbers with 0 to be counted? Can you use the Counter class?

#1: Count items from 0 to len(number_list) including items with count of 0, using Counter.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
>>> count = Counter(number_list)
>>> number_count_dict = {i:(count[i] if i in number_list else 0) for i in range(len(number_list))}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```

#2: Count items from lowest number to highest number in list including items with count of 0, using Counter.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> number_list = [2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7]
>>> count = Counter(number_list)
>>> number_count_dict = {i:(count[i] if i in number_list else 0) for i in range(min(number_list),max(number_list)+1)}
{2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 2}
```

#3: Count items in list using Counter.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
>>> count = Counter(number_list)
>>> number_count_dict = {i:count[i] for i in set(number_list)}
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

#4: Count items from 0 to len(number_list) including items with count of 0, NOT using Counter.

```
>>> number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
>>> number_count_dict = {i:number_list.count(i) for i in range(len(number_list))}
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```

#5: Count items from lowest number to highest number in list including items with count of 0, NOT using Counter.

```
>>> number_list = [2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7]
>>> number_count_dict = {i:number_list.count(i) for i in range(min(number_list),max(number_list)+1)}
{2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 2}
```

#6: Count items in list NOT using Counter.

```
>>> number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
>>> number_count_dict = {i:number_list.count(i) for i in set(number_list)}
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

#7: Bonus, using a defaultdict and for loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict 
number_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
number_count_dict = defaultdict(int)
for i in number_list:
    number_count_list[i] += 1
```